# WebBrowser Object - Get Element by Position

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get an element by position inside of a c# webbrowser object. Is this possible? I have been able to do it with javascript, but havent found the answer to this question yet.

I've found how to get the absolute position, but not how to actually select the item based on its actual position. Any thoughts?

Edit:

```
Position: X Y coordinates
Usecase: Selecting an input. And no I cannot rely on the id, name or dom order.
```

Comment: My question was downvoted because you couldnt answer it? Good job there.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried looking for a way to do it. It doesnt appear that anyone has ever tried to do this in the past. I have found how to get the X Y coords of the item, but I havent found anyone who has tried something even similar.

Answer (score 1):

With [`IHTMLDocument2::elementFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can get an element by arbitrary point coordinates. There are also some low-level methods which can be useful:

- `IDisplayServices::CreateDisplayPointer`
- `IDisplayServices::TransformPoint`
- `IDisplayPointer::MoveToPoint`
- `IDisplayPointer::GetFlowElement`